# Set PYTHONPATH and run python script in bash

Tags: bash, python-2.7, environment-variables

The bash script looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/expackage/"
python example.py
```

Let's call this bash script 'exbash'. The python script 'example.py' looks like the following:

```
try:
     from expackage import exmodule
     print 'it worked'
except:
     print 'it didn't work'
```

Issuing the command

```
./exbash
```

works fine. However, if I have `examply.py` call another script with imports `exmodule` such as

```
# Begin example.py
try:
     from example2 import ex2
     print 'it worked'
except:
     print 'it didn't work'
```

where example2.py looks something like

```
# Begin example2.py
from expackage import exmodule
class ex2:
     def __init__(self):
     ..........
if __name__== "__main__":
     ..........
```

the module fails to load in `example2.py`. Namely I get the error

```
File "/path/to/example2.py", line .., in <module>
from expackage.exmodule import something
ImportError: No module named expackage.exmodule
```

Comment: Using 'source exbash' gives the same error

Comment: You don't import from directories, you import from packages and modules. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sorry I had meant package, not directory. The issue still stands however

Comment: Does `directory` have a `__init__.py` ?

Comment: Yes, it does have a `__init__.py`

Comment: I have updated the question to get rid of the misunderstanding